# Is it correct to write a MySQL query like this?

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone what i want to know is if  writing a query like this is correct:

```
SELECT (SELECT t.name FROM type t WHERE t.id=a.id_type) AS TYPE,
       a.title title,a.description description,u.name name,u.email email
FROM advert a 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=a.id_user  
WHERE a.id='2';
```

I tested the query and it works, but what i want to know if it is correct by the standards to use a subquery and then a join .
Sorry if my question is stupid but i could't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed. It's called a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery). However, I think MySQL usually executes joins better:

```
SELECT t.name AS type, a.title title,a.description description,u.name name,u.email email
FROM advert a
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=a.id_user
LEFT JOIN type t ON t.id = a.id_type
WHERE a.id = '2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried it with a join too but i have a project for my class where i have to use at least 4 queries that have a sub-query in them so i thought i could use this one like that.(I don't know how are they called in English but ,my teacher calls them complex queries - that would be the word if i would translate from my language)

Answer (score 0):

It's correct but I think better to use a JOIN instead of a subquery. Also if you use a subquery you should to make sure it returns only ONE row.

```
SELECT t.name AS TYPE,
       a.title title,a.description description,u.name name,u.email email
FROM advert a 
INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=a.id_user  
LEFT JOIN type t on t.id=a.id_type
WHERE a.id='2';
```